# Trying to compile a package on Launchpad, can't find GLib even though its specificed

Tags: deb, launchpad

When I try to build my package I get this weird issue about Glib:

```
 /usr/bin/ld: main_window.o: undefined reference to symbol 'ceilf@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

I have Glib in the required build packages and have added a bunch of PPAs that had Glib packages in them. I can't seem to make this error go away. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Setting _LDADD in automake fixed it but the paths are not dynamic.